# using Data from component into another one

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

i've two Components, One for the Front, One for Datas.

but i don't understand how to use data into the Front component from importing Data component.

Here the Data Component :

`

```
<script>
    import { writable } from "svelte/store";

  // Charger les scripts Firebase
  import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import {getFirestore, collection, onSnapshot, updateDoc, addDoc} from "firebase/firestore";
    import {firebaseConfig} from '/Firebase.js';
    import { doc, getDoc, setDoc, deleteDoc, deleteField } from "firebase/firestore";

  // Initialize Firebase
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore();
    const docRef = collection(db, "Forecaster_init");

  // Writable
  export let ArrayCall = writable(0);

  ArrayCall.subscribe(value => { // i don't know really how it's works here
    countValue = value;
  });

// récupérer les datas
const osef = onSnapshot(docRef, (querySnapshot) => {

    const Array = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const { cardCreated, titleCard } = doc.data();
        Array.push({
            id: doc.id,
        cardCreated,
        titleCard,
        });
  // insert values fo array on variable;
    ArrayCall.set(Array);
  });
}); 


</script>

<!-- Here the datas what i want to use on the Front component -->
$: 
{#each $ArrayCall as {titleCard}}
{console.log('Data :', titleCard)}
{/each}
```

`

I've looking any REPL what i can find on the web but nothing from i need to use ...

I would like to no longer call the data via the Front page but only via the component, so as not to call the data on each of the pages and to shorten the code

Here the part where I call the data in the Front code

`

```
{#each $ArrayCall as item}
          <div class="addList2">
            {item.id} -- {item.titleCard}
          </div>
         {/each}
```

`

Thanks very much

I tried to export the data but each time it returns me undefind, so I don't understand, what is the point of redefining the variable in the page where you want it to be called via the component data?

what I want is to simply retrieve the values of $ArrayCall via component import and use it all over the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your file structure works or why you separated the logic into two files, but if you're importing the `data` as a component you should declare the prop in the component as `bind:prop={prop}`

Assuming you have two files, one called `Data.svelte` and another called `Front.svelte`. In `Front.svelte` you should have this:

```
<script>
   import Data from 'Data.svelte'
   let arrayCall;
</script>

<Data bind:arrayCall={arrayCall}></Data> //the  bind: allows Data.svelte to write data into arrayCall
{#each $ArrayCall as item}
   <div class="addList2">
      {item.id} -- {item.titleCard}
   </div>
{/each}
```

The only difference in `Data.svelte` would be uncapitalizing `ArrayCall` and other variables just to follow convention as a JS variable instead of constructor, so it would be like this:

```
<script>
    import { writable } from "svelte/store";

  // Charger les scripts Firebase
  import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import {getFirestore, collection, onSnapshot, updateDoc, addDoc} from "firebase/firestore";
    import {firebaseConfig} from '/Firebase.js';
    import { doc, getDoc, setDoc, deleteDoc, deleteField } from "firebase/firestore";

  // Initialize Firebase
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore();
    const docRef = collection(db, "Forecaster_init");

  // Writable
  export let arrayCall = writable(0);

  arrayCall.subscribe(value => {
    countValue = value;
  });

// récupérer les datas
const osef = onSnapshot(docRef, (querySnapshot) => {

    const array = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const { cardCreated, titleCard } = doc.data();
        array.push({
            id: doc.id,
        cardCreated,
        titleCard,
        });
  // insert values fo array on variable;
    arrayCall.set(array);
  });
}); 


</script>
```

I hope this works or at least helps! Cheers!!